# phantomjs page.open fails as undefined

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have a Rails-Ember project which I've recently set up QUnit unit tests on and everything works great in the browser. I'm now trying to get it running on our Jenkins server headlessly.

For extra fun, our Jenkins server does not have access to the outside internet, because enterprise.

So I'm trying to do this with Phantomjs and the [PhantomJS Qunit Runner Plugin](https://github.com/jonkemp/qunit-phantomjs-runner). This works great on my local machine.

I'm attempting to run it on the CI server by spinning up a daemonized rails server, and then running the script against it.

```
# some environment variables are set up here
$ rails s -p 6000 --daemon
$ phantomjs vendor/assets/javascripts/runner.js http://localhost:6000/qunit
```

Which has been failing with "Unable to access network: fail"

```
$ wget http://localhost:6000/qunit
```

Will download the HTML page with all the right script tags and the QUnit Fixture, so everything is ready to be run as expected.

I modified the script to get some more information ala [this , and am capturing the reason on a resourceError:

```
page.onResouceError = function(resourceError) {
  page.reason = resourceError.errorString
}
```

The error then comes out

"Unable to access network: fail, because undefined"

So taking the script out and just running PhantomJS as a command line utility:

```
phantomjs > var page = require('webpage').create()
phantomjs > page.open("http://localhost:6000/qunit", function(status) { console.log status })
undefined
```

So I'm a little at the end of my rope here. I'm not sure what else to try.

For reference, the phantomjs binary I am using is 1.9.2

```
$ ./phantomjs -v
1.9.2
```

Comment: When running phantomjs locally, you probably need parentheses: `console.log(status)`. Have you tried it with the newest version? 1.9.8 (1.9.12 through npm)?